# how to add a attribute in existing xml using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript, tridion

I have below xml and I am using **VBSript** to generate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:ListItems xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ID="tcm:481-86880-2" Managed="10682">
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594051"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594088"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594089"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594090"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594343"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594344"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594578"/>
</tcm:ListItems>
```

Now I have got a pageURL (/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/maldives.aspx), this will be shown after matching the ID for example below pseudocode

From above XML ID will be matched and then we will add the **pageURL** attribute to above xml. So the output will come as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:ListItems xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ID="tcm:481-86880-2" Managed="10682">
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594051"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594088"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594089"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594090"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594343" pageURL="/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/maldives.aspx"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594344"/>
  <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594578"/>
</tcm:ListItems>
```

Please suggest using VBSCript

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example using [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742(VS.85).aspx).

```
Dim doc
Dim pageUrl
Dim itemNode

Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
doc.load("test.xml")
doc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:tcm='http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0'"

Set itemNode = doc.selectSingleNode("/tcm:ListItems/tcm:Item[@ID = 'tcm:481-594343']")

Set pageUrl = doc.createAttribute("pageURL") 
pageUrl.Value = "/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/maldives.aspx" 
itemNode.attributes.setNamedItem(pageUrl)
```

When applied to the XML sample you provided. It produces the following output.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:ListItems xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ID="tcm:481-86880-2" Managed="10682">
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594051"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594088"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594089"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594090"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594343" pageURL="/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/maldives.aspx"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594344"/>
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:481-594578"/>
</tcm:ListItems>
```

Comment: Many Thanks Garett, I am getting object required error on itemNode.attributes.setNamedItem(pageUrl), can you please suggest me!

Comment: It look's like itemNode is not defined. I edited the example.