# VBscript XML formatting issue

Tags: vbscript

I'm using vbscript to write form data to an XML file:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Set objRoot = xmlDoc.createElement("root")
xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot

Set objRecord = xmlDoc.createElement("document")
objRoot.appendChild objRecord

Set objElement=xmlDoc.createElement("field")
objElement.setAttribute "level", "system"
objElement.setAttribute "name", "Document Filename with Full Path"
objElement.setAttribute "value", "C:\out\test.pdf"
objrecord.appendChild(objElement)

Set objIntro = xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction ("xml","version='1.0'")
xmlDoc.insertBefore objIntro,xmlDoc.childNodes(0)

Call ParseAndSave("C:\out\test.xml", xmlDoc)

Function ParseAndSave(filePath, xmlDoc)
set xmlWriter = CreateObject("MSXML2.MXXMLWriter")
set xmlReader = CreateObject("MSXML2.SAXXMLReader")
Set xmlStream = CreateObject("ADODB.STREAM")
xmlStream.Open
xmlStream.Charset = "UTF-8"

xmlWriter.output = xmlStream
xmlWriter.indent = True
xmlWriter.encoding = "UTF-8"

Set xmlReader.contentHandler = xmlWriter
Set xmlReader.DTDHandler = xmlWriter
Set xmlReader.errorHandler = xmlWriter
xmlReader.putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", xmlWriter
xmlReader.putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", xmlWriter

xmlReader.parse xmlDoc
xmlWriter.flush

xmlStream.SaveToFile filePath, 2

xmlStream.Close
Set xmlStream = Nothing
Set xmlWriter = Nothing
Set xmlReader = Nothing
End Function
```

It works, but the output not formatting like expect from an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <document>
        <field level="system" name="Document Filename with Full Path" value="C:\out\test.pdf"/>
    </document>
</root>
```

expected result. All new line aligned to left and between name and value got sapce

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
<document>
<field level = "system" name = "Document Filename with Full Path" value = "C:\out\test.pdf"/>
</document>
</root>
```

Comment: You could try something like this with msxml http://stackoverflow.com/a/3500085/1684418 that is use the createAttribute() function

Comment: Thanks for command, looks not my issues. I need add a space being and after = (like this got spaces level = "system", but my outcome no space like level="system")

Comment: Why would you even *want* to do that? Indention visualizes the structure of the XML for human readers, and it's ignored by automated processing anyway. And the additional spaces around the `=` do not contribute to readability either.

Comment: it's a integrate between existing DMS and new scanning system. I need use xml file to upload the source file to DMS and found the DMS cannot upload without the spaces around = , if use normal xml format with tag for the child element also not work.

Comment: You're entrusting your documents to a DMS that can't even get data *import* right? Wow.

Comment: Yes, due to the the formatting without space.